# How Remove custom Validators with method RemoveValidators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms, angular2-form-validation

I have a question how can I remove my custom validators in the easiest/best way?
I know that since angular 12 there is a method `RemoveValidators`, it is based on the reference of a given validator, that is, it is not easy to remove it.

What is the best way to remove such validators with parameters ?

Below i added stackblitz with non working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-arm6g6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code fails is because you are incorrectly passing the reference to your method.

Every time you call `AppComponent.forbiddenNameValidator(/admin|test|abc/)` you return a new anonymous function.

In your code, you are calling it twice, first in line 25 and then in line 37. Each of the calls generates a new anonymous function which has its own reference. You can prove this by simply doing the following test:

```js
const first = AppComponent.forbiddenNameValidator(/admin|test|abc/);
const second = AppComponent.forbiddenNameValidator(/admin|test|abc/);

console.log(first === second) // false
```

Then, how do we fix this?

According to the [Official Documentation](https://v14.angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#reference-to-a-validatorfn), you need to store the return value of the validator in a `const` or `property`.

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-uastc3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fname.validator.ts) contains a link with this approach.
Notice that the return of the validator is being stored in a property:

```js
forbiddenNameValidator = ForbiddenNameValidator(/admin|test|abc/);f
```

This property is then passed in validators array and in the `removeValidators` method. Also note that I added the call to the
`updateValueAndValidity()` of the form after removing the validator.

This is because according to the documentation, you should always call the `updateValueAndValidity()` of the form whose validators where altered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the *instance* of the validator to remove it.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Custom Validator Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  static forbiddenNameValidator(regex: RegExp) {
    return ForbiddenNameValidator(regex);
  }

  //Create an instance of the validator
  myCustomValidatorInstance =
    AppComponent.forbiddenNameValidator(/admin|test|abc/);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      FirstName: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          this.myCustomValidatorInstance,  //add the instance of the validator
        ],
      ],
    });
  }
  get firstname() {
    return this.form.controls['FirstName'];
  }

  removeCustomValidator() {
    //provide the same instance of the validator to remove it
    this.form.get('FirstName').removeValidators(this.myCustomValidatorInstance);
  }
}
```

[Here's an updated version of your stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-fmc5k5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

you need store the result of the validator in a property and then pass that property in the validators array and removeValidators method. After calling the removeValidators method, and also call the updateValueAndValidity() method to update the form control.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ForbiddenNameValidator } from './forbidden-name.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.forbiddenNameValidator]);

  forbiddenNameValidator = ForbiddenNameValidator(/admin|test|abc/);

  removeValidator() {
    this.name.removeValidators(this.forbiddenNameValidator);
    this.name.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

}